# ¿Cómo subo un proyecto a GitHub si el index.html no está en la carpeta raíz, sino en otra llamada "src" dentro de la misma?

Tags: html, css, github, tailwind

Estoy usando Tailwind y metí el `index.html` en una carpeta llamada `src`, entonces si subo el repositorio así, me dará error al ver el deploy en github, ya que el `index.html` no está en la raíz

¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

Comment: ¿Qué error te da? Podrías agregarlo a la pregunta?